# Baked Hair rendering is limp and differs from unbaked

Tags: baking, hair

I have a "Big Hair" Particles set-up that is having problems Baking properly.  If I render the frames without baking (ctl-F12), I get what I was hoping for.  But if I first Bake the Dynamics, I get totally limp hair starting from frame 1:

[image]

and it also goes through a Collision Object:

[image]

I cannot understand why these are so different, and I need to Bake the Hair if I'm going to submit an animation to a rendering farm.   Here is [image]

Comment: How this should look like or animate? When I try to bake this my Blender almost freezes. Do you need 22 quality steps? Just wondering because I can't see much movement here.

Comment: @Blunder -- if I render without baking, it looks like the "bushy Afro" on the left.  22 steps is not unusually high from my experience, but *anything* that works is welcome!  My blender is not overly stressed on my platform.  Try "unbake All" and then ctl-F12